# Processing Payment with PayPay after authorizing with Apple Pay

Tags: php, paypal, applepay, paypal-nvp, applepayjs

I have a shopping cart that currently uses a PayPal NVP to accept credit cards as well as checkout with PayPal accounts.

I've integrated Apple Pay, and am now on to actually processing the payment after Apple has validated the transaction. How do I use the payment data/tokens with PayPal to actually capture the funds and process the purchase?

I keep seeing a lot of references to Braintree, but thats a whole separate product, similar looking to Stripe.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's only available through BrainTree; confirmed by PayPal customer support.